# Embedded Table scroll vertical with fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-tables

I have a table which is embedded in another div, of course the size is bigger than the outer div. I am currently using [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) to fix the header on top while scrolling and leave it again when content of table is out of viewport. That works but what is really ugly is that while header-row is fixed it is greater than the content and so it overflows on left/right.

Please see [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0gmwe0f/1/) where it does work as described.
What I can imagine is somehow set a fix height and width of the table and it should be vertically and horizontally scrollable as there are overflows and the first row should be fixed on scrolling.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollLeft = 0;
  var leftRoundingRect = $('.table-body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;

  $('.sticky').scrollToFixed({
    limit: $('.user.last').offset().top,
    removeOffsets: true,
    zIndex: 0,
    unfixed: function() {
      $(this).offset({
        left: leftRoundingRect - scrollLeft
      });
    }
  });

  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    $(".user.sticky").offset({
      left: leftRoundingRect - scrollLeft
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.inner-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.table-body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.users {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.user {
  font-size: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  color: #555;
  width: 750px;
}

.user.odd {
  background: #f4f5f7;
}

.sticky {
  background: grey;
}

.bold {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.company,
.firstName,
.lastName,
.roles {
  font-size: 18px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <div class="users">
      <div class="user sticky">
        <div class="firstName bold">First</div>
        <div class="lastName bold">Last</div>
        <div class="roles bold">Role</div>
        <div class="company bold">Company</div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-body">
        <div class="user">
          <div class="firstName">Max</div>
          <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
          <div class="roles">admin</div>
          <div class="company">HP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user odd">
          <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
          <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
          <div class="roles">readonly</div>
          <div class="company">IBM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user">
          <div class="firstName">Max</div>
          <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
          <div class="roles">admin</div>
          <div class="company">HP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user odd">
          <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
          <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
          <div class="roles">readonly</div>
          <div class="company">IBM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user">
          <div class="firstName">Max</div>
          <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
          <div class="roles">admin</div>
          <div class="company">HP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user odd">
          <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
          <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
          <div class="roles">readonly</div>
          <div class="company">IBM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user last">
          <div class="firstName">Test</div>
          <div class="lastName">Tester</div>
          <div class="roles">contributor</div>
          <div class="company">SAP</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; height: 1000px; padding-top:50px;">Let's Scroll Baby
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Code does Work as I described it should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollLeft = 0;
  var leftRoundingRect = $('.table-body')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;

  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
    scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    $(".user.sticky").offset({
      left: leftRoundingRect - scrollLeft
    });
  });
  
  $(".user").width($(".table-body").get(0).scrollWidth - 1);
  
});
```

```css
.tab {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  width:220px;
}
.inner-content {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  width:200px;
}
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table-body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
.users {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.user {
  font-size: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  color: #555;
  width: 750px;
}
.user.odd {
  background: #f4f5f7;
}
.sticky {
  background: grey;
}
.bold {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.company,
.firstName,
.lastName,
.roles {
  font-size: 18px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; height: 200px; padding-top:50px;">Other Content
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="user sticky">
        <div class="firstName bold">First</div>
        <div class="lastName bold">Last</div>
        <div class="roles bold">Role</div>
        <div class="company bold">Company</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-body">
      <div class="user">
        <div class="firstName">Max</div>
        <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
        <div class="roles">admin</div>
        <div class="company">HP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user odd">
        <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
        <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
        <div class="roles">readonly</div>
        <div class="company">IBM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user">
        <div class="firstName">Max</div>
        <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
        <div class="roles">admin</div>
        <div class="company">HP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user odd">
        <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
        <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
        <div class="roles">readonly</div>
        <div class="company">IBM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user">
        <div class="firstName">Max</div>
        <div class="lastName">Mustermann</div>
        <div class="roles">admin</div>
        <div class="company">HP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user odd">
        <div class="firstName">Melanie</div>
        <div class="lastName">Musterfrau</div>
        <div class="roles">readonly</div>
        <div class="company">IBM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user last">
        <div class="firstName">Test</div>
        <div class="lastName">Tester</div>
        <div class="roles">contributor</div>
        <div class="company">SAP</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; height: 200px; padding-top:50px;">Other Content
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```